# How can I use for loop with array of string with filter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I get array of strings as a parameter and I want to use filter for every each string in this array and return matched results.

```
  get moviesByCity() {
    return (id: string[]): MovieI[] | undefined => {
      console.log(id);
      for (let i = 0; i <= id.length; i++) {
        console.log(id.length);
        console.log(id[i]);
        console.log(i);
        return this.movies.filter((movie) => movie.city === id[i]);
      }
    };
  }
```

The thing is my 'i' doesn't get iterated and it stays '0'. Where did i make a mistake?

[image]

I did console.log in the same order: 'id.length', 'id[i]' and 'i'

Comment: `return` terminates a function

Comment: How could I work around this then?

Comment: Try saving `this.movies.filter((movie) => movie.city === id[i]);` into an array and return the array after the loop.

Comment: There will be scope issue if i will try to use id[i] outside of for loop

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want intend to do, but here is my approximation.

Your have structurely messed up, using functions in wrong way.

Refer to docs for usage of functions like map, filter and some

```js
const moviesByCity = (id: string[]): MovieI[] | undefined => {
  console.log(id);
  return id.map((e,idx)=>{
    console.log(id[idx]);
    console.log(e);
    return movies.some((movie) => movie.city === e);
  })
};
```

Comment: It look alright and it would work in JS, the thing is I use it in getter in vuex module so to pass a parameter I need to return (id: string[]) as I did :<

Comment: @Goteii Ah, forgot returning. return the result of id.map

Comment: Thats not what I meant exactly. You pass parameter to function like const moviesByCity = (parameter) => ...
I use my function as a getter for vuex module store which cant  get parameters in functions, thats why I need to do 'const moviesByCity() { return (id: string[]) ...... }'

Comment: Don't you get the gist tho?

Comment: I did, sadly it doesn't recognize 'any' as a method. "Property 'any' does not exist on type MovieI"

Comment: My mistake. Use "some"  
https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: The thing is it will return boolean if it will find matching result. I want to return the whole array of matching objects so If I choose 'Tokio' and 'Oslo' which will get into id: string[] I want to get every movie which has 'movie.city = 'Tokio'' or 'movie.city = 'Oslo''

Comment: It can be implemented with my answer. Think a bit